# You know who I am -- do you?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> None stand above me.
>
> Except when none stand below me.
>
> Be careful with me...wish for me now, and love me now -- you may fear
>   me seconds later.
>
> I am small, but I have given so much.
>
> I am small, but I have taken so much away.
>
> Hearts in my world there are many -- larger than mine not any.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 18):

You are

> an **ace**.

None stand above me.

> Ace is the highest rank.

Except when none stand below me.

> Ace can also be the lowest rank.

Be careful with me...wish for me now, and love me now -- you may fear me seconds later.

> Aces are used in card games that involve chance, when an ace might help you one moment or help your opponent in another moment.

I am small, but I have given so much.

> The ace is sometimes represented with the small number 1. Aces are powerful cards that have won individuals money in popular card games.

I am small, but I have taken so much away.

> With their power, aces have also taken money away from the opponents of those receiving them.

Hearts in my world there are many -- larger than mine not any.

> *Hearts* are a suit, and the ace of hearts (sometimes) has the largest heart on it.

Comment: This is the first thing I thought about when I read the puzzle, but I think the whole answer is your answer + "of hearts"

Answer (score 1):

You are

> The Death

None stand above me.

> Dead people go to heaven.

Except when none stand below me.

> When you get burried underground, does nobody stand below you, so everyone on earth stands above you.

Be careful with me...wish for me now, and love me now -- you may fear me seconds later.

> People are afraid of the death.

I am small, but I have given so much.

> The death has given much pain to relatives.

I am small, but I have taken so much away.

> The death takes many lives.

Hearts in my world there are many -- larger than mine not any.

> Not very sure about this one but, love for the people who died.

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> A defibrillator.

None stand above me.

> Normally a defibrillator is stored away, not in use.

Except when none stand below me.

> A defibrillator is needed when someone is having a heart attack.  They won't be standing, but paramedics will be standing over them.

Be careful with me...wish for me now, and love me now -- you may fear me seconds later.

> The tool is a very dangerous last resort which has to be handled carefully.

I am small, but I have given so much.

> Referring to saving lives.

I am small, but I have taken so much away.

> Possibly referring to the dangers of using one.

Hearts in my world there are many -- larger than mine not any.

> The most direct clue, followed by a bit of personification.